# I want my visitors to go in my root directory file.php

Tags: directory, dns, root, program-entry-point, subdirectory

I have in a subfolder a wordpress site. There is a  index.php file there too.
I copied the content of subfolder to httpdocs main (root) directory. In this root directory there is a htaccess file and the index.php file too.
What must to do for my website visitors to go to https://example.com  and NO to https://example.com/wordpress ??
Thank you!

I need a solution for my website.